# How to distinguish between a sub-string and exact word?

Tags: python, string, string-matching

I am trying to solve a text matching problem in which I'm trying to find the matching between to listings of products with no incorrect matching. The marching is done through text similarity. The problem is that assume I have `"product G1234"` in one listing and  `"product G1"` in the other one where all the other features for these two elements are the same. the  `string operator` `in` in python is not a good option here since it matches these two products (and it shouldn't), anybody got any suggestion?

Comment: Check for EOL and spaces?

Comment: `in` isn't a string function, it's an operator.

Comment: Hard to understand what exactly you need. But maybe you read about Levenshtein distance algorithm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a regex which uses word boundaries `\b` to do an exact word match. `\b` matches between a word character and a non-word character (*vice-versa*). Here you can't use split since the substring you want to check for contains a space in the middle.

```
\bsub_string\b
```

**Example:**

```
>>> re.search(r'\bproduct G1\b', "product G1234")
>>> re.search(r'\bproduct G1\b', "product G1")
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 10), match='product G1'>
>>>
```

**OR**

```
>>> re.search(r'(?<!\S)product G1(?!\S)', "product G1")
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 10), match='product G1'>
>>> re.search(r'(?<!\S)product G1(?!\S)', "product G1234")
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this works. But do you know the efficiency of re.search algorithm? seems like taking a while, and as I'm dealing with megabytes text files, I don' t have the option to use time consuming algorithms

Comment: Just iterate over each line and then apply the above regex over each. I suggest you to use `re.search` since `re.match` will try to match the input line from the start.

Comment: What if the search word is an iterator such as `for i in Dictionary:  if re.search('\\b'+i+'\\b',line): print(i,'\t',line)`  Is that correct?  Seems to work for me, just wondering if there's a better method.